# Struggling to build with Detox

Tags: android, react-native, jestjs, automated-tests, detox

I am looking to setup automated end to end UI testing for React Native App and its my first time doing it using detox.

I followed exact steps as mentioned in this article:
https://varunon9.medium.com/e2e-testing-of-react-native-app-android-using-detox-a-step-by-step-guide-bfb520c1a9ac

But every time I try to run build command i.e: detox build -c android.emu.debug. I get the following error:

[Here is the console log from when I run the command]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbLlO.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The error is as follows: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: I was able to solve this. It was a stupid mistake instead of ./gradlew in build command I was supposed to use just gradlew as that's how the file was saved inside my android folder of the project

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this. It was a stupid mistake instead of **./gradlew** in build command I was supposed to use just **gradlew** as that's how the file was saved inside my android folder of the project